# Flex Tile that expands as items are added to it

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, tile

```
<mx:Tile width="100%" height="20">
    <mx:Button label="btn"/>
    <mx:Button label="btn"/>
    <mx:Button label="btn"/>
    <mx:Button label="btn"/>
    <mx:Button label="btn"/>
    <mx:Button label="btn"/>
</mx:Tile>
```

The above Tile has a height of 20. When I add 50 new buttons to it, a vertical scrollbar is added. How can I make it not show the scrollbar but change it's height dynamically so that all the added items are always shown. Kinda like an "expanding" tile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WindowShade component from flexlib solved this. It can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList (look for **WindowShade**)

Here's a sample: http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/WindowShade_Sample.swf

Answer (score 0):

According to the Flex Documentation, the height of the Tile-container is set dynamically:

> Default height of the Tile container is equal to (tile cell default height) x (rounded square root of the number of children), plus any gaps between children and any padding. Default width is equal to (tile cell default width) x (rounded square root of the number of children), plus any gaps between children and any padding.

I think removing the width and height should do the trick.

Comment: Nice that works. But, doesn't work when I want the width to be fixed. I'm trying to create left menus like http://www.picnik.com/app#/create/shapes Any ideas on how this can be achieved?